# Panda dataframe.apply: using lambda function with apply() and refering to previous row

Tags: pandas, lambda

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Compute a column within a dataframe for which a cell's value depends on the previous one
- use apply & lambda function to contain the logic/formula

I'm doing the following (I'll manage indexes better than with a try/except, but for testing):

```
def func(row, df_foo):
    i = row.name
    try:
        new_row = df_foo["bar"].iloc[i-1] + row.name  # or wathever computation
    except:
        new_row = 1
    return new_row
```

I'm calling it this way:

```
df_foo["bar"] = df_p1.apply(lambda row:func(row, df_foo), axis=1)
```

However, when I access df_foo.bar within func(), the previous value hasn't been calculated. I'm guessing the updated value isn't accessible fron within the lambda? Or it's updated only after the lambda evaluates for all values?

Is there a way that I could keep this general structure, while accessing update values for `df_foo["bar"].iloc[i-1]` within `func()`?

Comment: Are you against using `df.shift` or `df.rolling`? `df.shift` will do exactly what you are trying above but you're alluding to an unseen function you are attempting to calculate.

Comment: I don't think you can vectorize recursive functions like this. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008390/how-to-constuct-a-column-of-data-frame-recursively-with-pandas-python

Comment: @YoannQuenachdeQuivillic Yeah I had seen that answer.  I was hoping to figure out a way to use apply/lambda, but perhaps you're right and I should just loop it.

Comment: @fam-woodpecker actual computation needs to take place. This example is just for the general structure, but I'm not looking to just move the index. Wasn't all that clear I guess. Edited