In a pandas dataframe, for a given column, How to multiple a value in same row of df with another value in previous row of its own column?
I want to transform a datafram like this
date     |     colA     |       ColB
------------------------------------
1971-10-01   0.002451            NaN
1971-11-01   0.002445            NaN
1971-12-01   0.002439            NaN
1972-01-01   0.002433            NaN
1972-02-01   0.004854            NaN
1972-03-01   0.000000    250341816.0
1972-04-01   0.002415            NaN
1972-05-01   0.002410            NaN
1972-06-01   0.002404            NaN

to
date     |     colA     |       ColB
------------------------------------
1971-10-01   0.002451            0
1971-11-01   0.002445            0
1971-12-01   0.002439            0
1972-01-01   0.002433            0
1972-02-01   0.004854            0
1972-03-01   0.000000    250341816.0
1972-04-01   0.002415    250946391.486
1972-05-01   0.002410    251551172.289
1972-06-01   0.002404    252155901.307

There was only one valid value in colB ie 250341816.0 and rest all rows were NaN, the rows above it has to be filled with 0 but i-th row below it have to be filled with
df[ColB].iloc[i] = df[ColB].iloc[i-1] * (1 + df[ColA].iloc[i])
for example as you can see
250341816.0*(1+0.002415)=250946391.486
I am looking for a concise way to do it, preferably not via looping all indices explicitly.

In short - you can't, it has to be a loop :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008390/how-to-constuct-a-column-of-data-frame-recursively-with-pandas-python

Looks like just a cumprod on colA + 1

Code
cond = df['colB'].shift().isna().cummin()

df['colB'] = (
    df['colA']
    .mask(cond, 0)
    .add(1)
    .cumprod()
    .mul(df['colB'].ffill(), fill_value=0)
)

df
         date     colA             colB
0  1971-10-01 0.002451         0.000000
1  1971-11-01 0.002445         0.000000
2  1971-12-01 0.002439         0.000000
3  1972-01-01 0.002433         0.000000
4  1972-02-01 0.004854         0.000000
5  1972-03-01 0.000000 250341816.000000
6  1972-04-01 0.002415 250946391.486000
7  1972-05-01 0.002410 251551172.289000
8  1972-06-01 0.002404 252155901.307000

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'date': ['1971-10-01', '1971-11-01', '1971-12-01', '1972-01-01', '1972-02-01', '1972-03-01', '1972-04-01', '1972-05-01', '1972-06-01'], 'colA': [0.002451, 0.002445, 0.002439, 0.002433, 0.004854, 0.0, 0.002415, 0.00241, 0.002404], 'colB': [float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 250341816.0, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

